# In PowerShell, how do I test whether or not a specific variable exists in global scope?

Tags: powershell

I'm using PowerShell scripts for some UI automation of a WPF application.  Normally, the scripts are run as a group, based on the value of a global variable.  It's a little inconvenient to set this variable manually for the times when I want to run just one script, so I'm looking for a way to modify them to check for this variable and set it if not found.

`test-path variable:\foo` doesn't seem to work, since I still get the following error:

> The variable '$global:foo' cannot be retrieved because it has not been set.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**EDIT:** Use [stej's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3163008/788168) below. My own (partially incorrect) one is still reproduced here for reference:

---

You can use

```
Get-Variable foo -Scope Global
```

and trap the error that is raised when the variable doesn't exist.

Comment: I'd personally go with stej's answer; I commented so on it and I upvoted it as well. I just cannot remove this one anymore.

Comment: I wouldn't. This answer is more specific to the action that's occurring, improving code readability.

Comment: @VertigoRay: Using exceptions as control-flow mechanisms always has a bit of a bad smell to me. Yes, historically you've been forced to do that in shell languages but that doesn't make it a particular good idea. In this case you want to check for existence of a variable. `Test-Path` on the Variable provider does exactly that. Get-Variable gives you the value or an error.

Comment: You don't have to trap the error. `Get-Variable foo -Scope Global -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` works just fine. For example: `if (Get-Variable foo -Scope Global -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) { $true } else { $false }` will output: `False`

Comment: I posted another solution that encumpasses what I'm talking about.

Comment: @Vertigo: Good point about `-ea`, but still, `Get-Variable` doesn't exactly say »does this variable exist?«, but rather »hand me this variable«. \*shrugs\* There are plenty of options in PowerShell and it usually comes down to individual preference. Despite this being my answer, this isn't *my* particular preference here. Although my writing style may be rare anyway.

Comment: That's a good point. I do prefer the EAFP style of programming, and it is all preference. :cheers:

Comment: A shorter version of @VertigoRay's comment also works using the alias for the `ErrorAction` parameter name and enum value for `SilentlyContinue`: `Get-Variable foo -EA 0`

Comment: In PowerShell 7+, if you want a line of code to run, but you don't want to surround it with an if block, you can use `Get-Variable foo *>$null && "Variable exists" || "Variable doesn't exist"`

Think of it like a ternary operator that can handle functions, like this for example: `Get-Variable foo *>$null && Write-Output "Variable exists" || Write-Error "Variable doesn't exist"`

Answer (score 261):

[`Test-Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/test-path?view=powershell-7) can be used with a special syntax:

```
Test-Path variable:global:foo
```

This also works for environment variables (`$env:foo`):

```
Test-Path env:foo
```

And for non-global variables (just `$foo` inline):

```
Test-Path variable:foo
```

Comment: Thx ;) imo that's the correct way, no such workaround like `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` or `try/catch` with `Get-Variable`.

Comment: I used this concept, but in my case I had to test for variable:local:foo

Comment: If the variable is not global, make sure to not include the "global" part.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work when I test for a parameter given on the command line.  `param([string]$name) <CR>test-path global:variable:name` i get back False.   Is a parameter not a variable?  I also tried local:variable and (global|local):parameter.

Comment: Would someone mind providing the documentation for this syntax?

Comment: @JoshGust I've linked to the syntax. Unfortunately, this usecase is not documented.

Comment: @JoshGust the documentation is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes?view=powershell-7#scope-modifiers) under `variable-namespace`. You can also do `Write-Output $variable:foo` to get the value of `foo`

Comment: Doesn't work on $input

Answer (score 24):

Personal preference is to use `Ignore` over `SilentlyContinue` here because it's not an error at all. Since we're expecting it to potentially be `$false` let's prevent it (with `Ignore`) from being put (albeit silently) in the `$Error` stack.

You can use:

```
if (Get-Variable 'foo' -Scope 'Global' -ErrorAction 'Ignore') {
    $true
} else {
    $false
}
```

More tersely:

```
[bool](gv foo -s global -ea ig)
```

**Output of either:**

```
False
```

## Alternatively

You can trap the error that is raised when the variable doesn't exist.

```
try {
    Get-Variable foo -Scope Global -ErrorAction 'Stop'
} catch [System.Management.Automation.ItemNotFoundException] {
    Write-Warning $_
}
```

**Outputs:**

```
WARNING: Cannot find a variable with the name 'foo'.
```

## Discussion

I don't prefer `Test-Path variable:global:foo` because `variable:` is pointing to a provider, and that reference may be removed if your code is running in an environment/computer that you don't control. It's the same reason I don't use `HKLM:` and prefer `Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`.

Run `Get-PSDrive` to see the providers that are exposed.

Comment: Agree: Since you're checking for it, it's not an error.  Should be "Ignore"d.

Comment: Doesn't work on $input

Comment: It doesn't work the way you're expecting on `$input`. The problem is that `$input` is an [Automatic Variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables#input), so it's always set.

Answer (score 7):

Simple:

```
 [boolean](get-variable "Varname" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can assign a variable to the return value of Get-Variable then check to see if it is null:

```
$variable = Get-Variable -Name foo -Scope Global -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

if ($variable -eq $null)
{
    Write-Host "foo does not exist"
}

# else...
```

Just be aware that the variable has to be assigned to something for it to "exist". For example:

```
$global:foo = $null

$variable = Get-Variable -Name foo -Scope Global -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

if ($variable -eq $null)
{
    Write-Host "foo does not exist"
}
else
{
    Write-Host "foo exists"
}

$global:bar

$variable = Get-Variable -Name bar -Scope Global -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

if ($variable -eq $null)
{
    Write-Host "bar does not exist"
}
else
{
    Write-Host "bar exists"
}
```

Output:

```
foo exists
bar does not exist
```

Answer (score 2):

So far, it looks like the answer that works is [this one](http://www.vistax64.com/powershell/240033-detecting-variable-has-not-been-assigned-value.html#post1102457).

To break it out further, what worked for me was this:

```
Get-Variable -Name foo -Scope Global -ea SilentlyContinue | out-null
```

`$?` returns either true or false.

Comment: Further along in that thread, they mention that Test-Path variable:global:foo will work, as per stej's answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
$myvar = if ($env:variable) { $env:variable } else { "default_value" }
```

Comment: This does not work if the `$env:variable` is explicitly set to `false`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
$global:foo -eq $null
```

This will return `$true` if the `$global:foo` is not set.

Answer (score -1):

Test the existence of variavle MyVariable.
Returns boolean true or false.

`Test-Path variable:\MyVariable`

Answer (score -5):

If `$variable` is not of type `bool`, then there's an even easier way:

```
if($variable){
    Write-Host "bar exist"
}else{
    Write-Host "bar does not exists"
}
```

Comment: What if $variable does exist, but equal to $false?