# powershell testing a variable that hasnt being assign yet

Tags: variables, powershell, if-statement, conditional-statements

I want to test to see if a variable has been assigned a variable and if not perform action.  How can this be achieve?

I've attempted it with the following code but receive the error: The right operand of '-is' must be a type.

$ProgramName is not assigned at this point.

```
If ($ProgramName -isnot $null) {
    $ProgramName = $ProgramName + ', ' + $cncPrograms
}
Else {
    If ($cncPrograms -isnot $null) {
    $ProgramName = $cncPrograms 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Any unassigned variable will have a value of null, not a data type of null.  So, just do this:

```
If ($ProgramName -ne $null)
```

...that will return `TRUE` if it's been assigned to a non-null value.

An even easier check to make is

```
IF($ProgramName)
```

Which will check if that is `$null` or not, though the logic is reversed, so you could use

```
IF(!$ProgramName)
```

**Edit:**

Ruffin raises a good point about strictmode in comments. This method will work as well:

`Test-Path variable:ProgramName` or `Test-Path variable:global:ProgramName` if it's explicitly global scoped, for instance. This will return `$true` or `$false` depending on if the variable exists.

Comment: Thanks. I found your explanation more useful after reading through the article Andy Arismendi posted.  It makes total sense now! Thanks for posting.

Comment: I don't *think* that works with `Set-StrictMode -version latest;`, correct? How should you check for it when strict mode is on? **EDIT** Apparently [`Test-Path variable:global:foo
`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3163008/1028230)

Comment: @ruffin `Test-path variable:ProgramName` will return `$true` or `$false`. Good catch on strictmode. I added that to the answer.

Comment: If using Test-Path, don't be me and forget to remove the $ from the variable name :(

Comment: This answer contains one of the most common PowerShell gotchas, i.e., the counter-intuitive way that equality operators work on arrays (see [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-arrays#-eq-and--ne)). Essentially, if `$ProgramName` happens to be an array with `$null` as all of its values, the statement will return `$false` despite the variable being not null (i.e., an array). The fix is to simply switch the comparison by putting $null on the left side: `If ($null -ne $ProgramName)`

Answer (score 11):

`Test-Path variable:\var` should do what you want, I guess.

Comment: Yeah. works too.  So many ways to check.  IS this not a good method? just asking because you finished your sentence with "i guess" .

Comment: This is truly the correct answer. The other way to do it is technically a hack. This is the intended programmatic way to do it.

Answer (score 7):

Contrary to answers above

```
Test-Path variable:ProgramName
```

Might not be what you are looking for because it only tests for the existence of the variable.  If the Variable is set to $null it will still return $true.

Therefore in strictmode you may have to test for it's existence existence and whether it is non-empty.

```
Set-StrictMode -version Latest
#TODO Add a scope parameter
Function IsEmpty([string]$varname){
   if (Test-path "variable:$varname"){ 
      $val=(gi "variable:$varname").value
      if ($val -is [bool]) {$false}
      else {$val -eq '' -or $val -eq $null} }
   else{ $true }
}

#TEST:
if (test-path variable:foobar){remove-variable foobar} ; IsEmpty foobar
$foobar=$null; IsEmpty foobar
$foobar='';  IsEmpty foobar;
$foobar=$false;  IsEmpty foobar

#Results:
True
True
True
False
```

Strict mode kind of takes some of the fun out of scripting...

Answer (score 5):

Aside from the fact that -isnot is for types, in powershell 7 there's a new operator for this purpose.  The assignment will only happen if the left side is $null.

```
$programname ??= 'foo'
```

Answer (score 3):

To build on the (correct) answers from JNK and David, check out this great blog post from Jeffrey Snover that walks you through all the use cases of Boolean expressions in PoweShell. It concludes with how to test for the existence of a variable.

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/boolean-values-and-operators/

Comment: Thanks i read through and makes much more sense after reading the examples.

Answer (score 0):

-is or -isnot is to check to see the datatype the var is set to.  For example:

```
$Test -is [String] -or $Test -isNot [Int]
```

An undeclared $var can be evaluated using {$Test -eq $null} will return True.  If you nullify the $var anywhere in your code, you'll then need to evaluate differently.

I personally pre-set the $var's I am going to use in the script by nullifying them first.

```
[Array]$TestArray = @()
[String]$TestString = $null
```

Note that if you use [String]::Empty, and the var picks up any blank spaces this will not return True, it will be false.

```
$TestString -eq [String]::Empty
```

To evaluate a string if its empty and ignore any blank spaces use this method.

```
[string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($TestString)
```

To Evaluate if an array is empty, you have to use $var.Count.

```
$TestArray.Count -ge 1
```