# Test-Path to check for variable existence not behaving as I would expect

Tags: powershell

I have the following code in a PowerShell script:

```
Write-Host "clusterName=$clusterName"

Write-Host (Test-Path variable:global:clusterName)
```

which returns the following output:

```
clusterName=CorrectValue
False
```

Now clearly the variable exists (because it contains the value "CorrectValue") but if that's the case I would have expected the second call to `Write-Host` to return "true", not "false". I found the "Test-Path..." code at [In PowerShell, how do I test whether or not a specific variable exists in global scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3159949/in-powershell-how-do-i-test-whether-or-not-a-specific-variable-exists-in-global) but clearly its not behaving as I thought it would. Can anyone explain why?

TIA

Comment: When I run your code, it returns true for me, not false.

Comment: yes, if i run that code in isolation then it returns true. the difference is that that code is contained inside a script, a script which is actually deep down in the call stack. Seems as though there's some nuance that I don't know about that causes it to return false in a certain circumstance - I just can't figure out what that nuanced circumstance actually is. very annoying.

Comment: Where is $clusterName defined, can you give some more context, is it in a module, script, psake script?

Comment: The code above exists in a psake Task. Earlier in that same psake Task the .ps1 script that defines $clusterName gets dot-sourced.

Comment: Hmmm, not sure if that would work, take a read of this https://github.com/psake/psake/wiki/How-can-I-set-a-variable-in-one-task-and-reference-it-in-another%3F

Comment: Hello folks, I've figured out a solution. By declaring my variable as having global scope (i.e. $global:clusterName = "SomeValue") then everything works as expected. I haven't actually figured out *why* it doesn't work without explicitly declaring global scope (I think @LloydHolman might be onto something when he linked to that article about psake) however its now working for me, and that's the main thing I care about.

Comment: Just to backup the theory about psake affecting variable behaviour... I defined 

"$global:DebugPreference = "Continue"; $global:VerbosePreference = "Continue";" 
in the script that was dot-sourced however that did not turn on verbose and debug output for anything in the later-called psake task. The only way to turn on verbose and debug output for code inside the psake task is to explicitly set "$global:DebugPreference = "Continue";$global:VerbosePreference = "Continue";" at the top of the psake task. Its almost as if the psake stuff runs "out of process" (for want of a better term)"

Answer (score 2):

Variables defined in a script are not created at the global scope unless you explicitly use the `$global:` modifier for the variable name. (This is generally what you want, as global variables have a tendency to stick around after the script has completed.)

You could change your test function to look in the local namespace by using `Test-Path variable:local:clusterName`, or the script namespace with `Test-Path variable:script:clusterName` - both of these should be `$true`.