# Cannot convert argument second time in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to call a web service. If I just start up Powershell fresh, the following code runs perfectly. Any subsequent run will give the following error.

```
Cannot convert argument "fieldsWithValues", with value: 
"FileHold.LibraryManager.FieldWithValue[]", for "SetMetadata" to type 
"FileHold.LibraryManager.FieldWithValue[]": "Cannot convert the 
"FileHold.LibraryManager.FieldWithValue" value of type 
"FileHold.LibraryManager.FieldWithValue" to type 
"FileHold.LibraryManager.FieldWithValue"."
At Z:\VM_Transfer\Customers\Oregon\UpdateMetadata\CannotConvertTest.ps1:19 char:1
```

Here is the code with the problem.

```
$fh = "http://fileholdtest8/fh/filehold"

$uri = $fh + "/UserRoleManager/SessionManager.asmx?WSDL"
$SessionManager = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri $uri -Namespace FileHold.SessionManager
$sessionId = $SessionManager.StartSession( 'sysadm', '12345', 4 )

$uri = $fh + "/LibraryManager/DocumentManager.asmx?WSDL"
$dm = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri $uri -Namespace FileHold.LibraryManager

$dm.CookieContainer = New-Object System.Net.CookieContainer
$cookie = New-Object System.Net.Cookie( 'FHLSID', $sessionId, "/", ([System.Uri]$dm.Url).Host )
$dm.CookieContainer.Add( $cookie )    

$newFieldValue = [FileHold.LibraryManager.FieldWithValue]::new()
$newFieldValue.FieldId = 1007
$newFieldValue.FieldValue = $true
[FileHold.LibraryManager.FieldWithValue[]]$fieldsWithValues = @( $newFieldValue )

$dm.SetMetadata( 4033, 1002, "EmployeeInfo_filled1-test", $fieldsWithValues, $false, $null )
```

What do I need to do to be able to run this every time without restarting the ISE.

Btw. I can use this technique to call other methods without any problem as long as their parameters are simple types. It seems the issue only occurs when I have a complex object like **FileHold.LibraryManager.FieldWithValue**.

PSVersion = 5.1.14393.1532

Comment: I never use `New-WebServiceProxy` myself, but I am guess, that it is generate new set of proxy types each time you call it. Thus when you call it second time you actually get two different `[FileHold.LibraryManager.FieldWithValue]` types. Them happens to have same full name, but you can not convert between them.

Comment: I had tried some things along those lines, but kept failing. However, you have inspired me to look at it again and I see I was testing the existence of the web service reference variable incorrectly. I am fixing it with Test-Path as per [stej](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3159949/in-powershell-how-do-i-test-whether-or-not-a-specific-variable-exists-in-global) and it works.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by ensuring I do not reuse the variable. Of course, I will need to deal with a potential expired cookie, but that is another problem.

```
$fh = "http://fileholdtest8/fh/filehold"

$uri = $fh + "/UserRoleManager/SessionManager.asmx?WSDL"
$SessionManager = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri $uri -Namespace FileHold.SessionManager
$sessionId = $SessionManager.StartSession( 'sysadm', '12345', 4 )

if ( !(Test-Path variable:dm) )
{
    $uri = $fh + "/LibraryManager/DocumentManager.asmx?WSDL"
    $dm = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri $uri -Namespace FileHold.Library

    $FieldWithValueType = "{0}.FieldWithValue" -f $dm.GetType().Namespace

    $dm.CookieContainer = New-Object System.Net.CookieContainer
    $cookie = New-Object System.Net.Cookie( 'FHLSID', $sessionId, "/", ([System.Uri]$dm.Url).Host )
    $dm.CookieContainer.Add( $cookie )    
}

$newFieldValue = [FileHold.Library.FieldWithValue]::new()
$newFieldValue.FieldId = 1007
$newFieldValue.FieldValue = $true
$fieldsWithValues = @( ,$newFieldValue )

$dm.SetMetadata( 4041, 1002, "EmployeeInfo_filled1-test", $fieldsWithValues, $false, $null )
```