# Powershell ignore errors or warnings

Tags: powershell, variables

I had downloaded a powershell module called SecurityFever. In this lib there is a code part:

```
# Get the global impersonation context
$globalImpersonationContext = Get-Variable -Name 'ImpersonationContext' -Scope 'Global'

# Global variable to hold the impersonation context
if ($null -eq $globalImpersonationContext) {
    $stack = New-Object -TypeName 'System.Collections.Generic.Stack[System.Security.Principal.WindowsImpersonationContext]'
    New-Variable -Name 'ImpersonationContext' -Value $stack -Option ReadOnly -Scope Global -Force
}
```

it is absolutely clear what it is and what it wants to do, but when I execute this I got red lines in the console window:

> Get-Variable : Cannot find a variable with the name
>   'ImpersonationContext'. At SecurityFever.psm1:2427 char:35
>   + ... onContext = Get-Variable -Name 'ImpersonationContext' -Scope 'Global' ...

I think it is because the `get-variable` does not found this global variable for the 1st time. I am wondering

- how to suppress this error without modifying the external lib source code,
- or how to do a thing like this - checking if a variable exists or not.

I tried to create the expected global variable before the function call

```
ImpersonationContext = New-Object -TypeName 'System.Collections.Generic.Stack[System.Security.Principal.WindowsImpersonationContext]'
```

or

```
$global:ImpersonationContext = New-Object -TypeName 'System.Collections.Generic.Stack[System.Security.Principal.WindowsImpersonationContext]'
```

but somehow then it becomes a kind of PSVariable, and the code says

```
Method invocation failed because [System.Management.Automation.PSVariable] does not contain a method named 'Pop'.
```

I am not an expert in PowerShell, and I can say I totally can't understand why. :(

Comment: `$globalImpersonationContext = Get-Variable -Name 'ImpersonationContext' -Scope 'Global' -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` to supress the error?

Comment: This works, nice, thanks!

Comment: The 2nd problem still exisist :( It still says it is a PSVariable, not a Stack<WindowsImpersonationContext> typed (method .Pop does not exists). :(

Comment: Did you try the below solution?
It looks for the `ImpersonationContext` variable and if it doesn't exist, it will create one for you. It's the same code which you have mentioned.

Comment: Yes, I understand your code, but this is an external (3rd party) solution, which I do not want to modify. When I call the function of the module, and added to -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue the red error messages disappeared. This is better solution for me, but I am really grateful for your code snippet, I saved it to my snippet collection.

Comment: The real question remains - after the creation of the global variable - why it becomes a type of PSVariable and not a Stack<WindowsImpersonationContext> (the other error, the variable has no Pop method) still exists... :(

Comment: Add-Type -AssemblyName 'mscorlib' helped.

Answer (score 1):

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3159949/in-powershell-how-do-i-test-whether-or-not-a-specific-variable-exists-in-global), you can use `Test-Path` with a special syntax to check for your variable. You can do something like this -

```
if (Test-Path variable:global:ImpersonationContext)
{
    write-host "The variable ImpersonationContext exists in the global scope"
}
else
{
    $stack = New-Object -TypeName 'System.Collections.Generic.Stack[System.Security.Principal.WindowsImpersonationContext]'
    New-Variable -Name 'ImpersonationContext' -Value $stack -Option ReadOnly -Scope Global -Force
}
```